# How do I list a log all of the files with specific extension added deleted or modified on the branch in git?

Tags: windows, git, cmd, command-line, wildcard

The file was deleted, (or never added) that we need to the repo, we only now realized that we don't have it, months after when multiple changes came on top.

Is there a way to list all the merges/commits that happened on `main` that had changed (or even better if being added/deleted) to files with a specific file extension (or pattern).

Something like below, but for all commits?

`git ls-files *.pubxml`

Cannot use `grep`, this is on windows.

Comment: "Cannot use grep, this is on windows." - then use `findstr`

Comment: If you are using git on windows, grep should be available with git, as usually git for windows comes with bash and many other common gnu tools. Just look for bin directory in your git installation path

Comment: @Saboteur Thanks mate, that helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it with a combination of things:

1. Thanks to @Saboteur indeed I had `git-bash` installed in `C:\Program Files\Git`
2. Change dir to your repo (`cd c\repos\[repoWhereThe.GitFileIs]`)
3. Run `$ git log  --summary | grep -E '*.txt'`

[image]